# Create shortcut on MAC OS desktop

Tags: install4j

I am trying to figure out the way to create a desktop shortcut for MAC OS installation of my Java GUI application. The app is packaged into "macOS folder". It gets launched by a shell script in one of its folders. Is it possible to create a shortcut on a desktop to such script so that the terminal is not shown when launched? I can't make it take the argument for running the script. Also, I can't figure out the way to make the icon for such shortcut. Using install4j 6.1.6.

Comment: Have you tried with the "Add a desktop link" action?

Comment: I have but it's not very friendly for the end user because the terminal pops up. My app gets launched from its own shell script. I ended up packaging the application into .app package and sticking it into the "macOS folder". This lets user to drag the app anywhere including desktop or dock. BTW - I wish there was a proper way to create .app packages in install4j, I think it can be automated.